# Devoping Android Application With Prevoius Android Versions

Tags: android

Good day

I have some questions, I have searched around but the answers I found wasn't clear enough.
I am developing a simple android application and I want this application to be backward with the older android versions.

My question is if I had to start developing the application by selecting an older android API or if I start developing with the latest one, will the application be compatible with the android older versions?

Again, my application is very simple, it has some button linking to my website, I have test the application at eclipse by selecting at "Edit config: default" other android SDK's and seems the application to work fine.

But my question remains the same.

Thanks for support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While developing your application, you will be asked to specify the target sdk, and it determines which OS version your app will be installed.

If you want your app to run across various devices, you have to specify the target sdk accordingly,

and the issues which you might face is this,

if you use API of level 11 and your app runs on API level 8 , obviously API will throw error, because those APIs are not found in previous version.

Answer (score 0):

You need to select the lower of android version for your app. If while you're doing it, you need some function or property of an advanced android version, you can change it.

Anyway, i think if you select the last version, it's not sure that your app will work on previous android version, although you're not using special functions from the lasts versions.

Comment: That I was thinking about but I wasn't sure if I have to go forward like this. My worries and I have some, I have make some test app and the problem is obvious, tested the app to friends phones with older API versions, hasn't work! Doing by setting compatibility also hasn't work.